# Teradata: Sum Total Amount of Paid Claims by Duplicate DX Flag per Member

Tags: teradata

First, I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this, but it's the only way I've been able to make the code combine the DX's into one column.  Originally they were in separate columns as 0/1's and I needed them in one column. I tried the PIVOT function, but was not able to figure it out.

The issue is I need the paid amounts to be based on duplicated instances DX's.  Which sounds counterintuitive, but for this report it's what I need.

For example. If member A has COPD, ASTHMA, AND DIABETES. The member's paid claims were 40,000 so I need the paid amount for that member to reflect 120,000, etc. and so forth.

The code:

```
SELECT 
    DX_FLAG
    ,Sum( AMT_PAID) AS PHARM_PAID_AMT
    ,Count(DISTINCT(MEMBER_AMISYS_NBR)) AS MEMBER_COUNT 

FROM 
(SELECT 
        st.MEMBER_AMISYS_NBR 
        ,ph.PHARMACY_CLAIM_CK 
        ,ph.AMT_PAID 
            ,FILL.DATE_DATE AS Fill_Date 
        ,Coalesce(CASE WHEN DX_ASTHMA = 'ASTHMA' THEN 'Asthma' END,
        CASE WHEN DX_COPD = 'COPD' THEN 'COPD' END,
        CASE WHEN DX_DIABETES = 'DIABETES' THEN 'DIABETES' END,
        CASE WHEN DX_HEART_FAILURE = 'HEART FAILURE' THEN 'HEART_FAILURE' END,
        CASE WHEN DX_HYPERTENSION = 'HYPERTENSION' THEN 'HYPERTENSION' END)
        AS DX_FLAG
 FROM
  STATE_OVERALL_MBRS st
           JOIN FT_PHARMACY_CLAIM ph ON st.MEMBER_CURR_CK = ph.PRESCRIBER_MEMBER_CURR_CK AND ph.DELETED_IND = 'N'                        
           JOIN DIM_DATE FILL ON ph.FILL_DATE_DIM_CK = FILL.DATE_DIM_CK
 WHERE FILL.DATE_DATE BETWEEN '2021-10-01' AND '2022-09-30'  
          AND ph.PLAN_DIM_CK =10  
      AND  ph.REVERSAL_IND = 'N' 
      AND ph.AMT_PAID > 0
) rx
```

My output looks like this .

| DX_FLAG | PHARM_PAID_AMT | MEMBER_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DIABETES | 70,000,000 | 14,144 |
| COPD | 38,266,409 | 6,641 |
| HEART_FAILURE | 10,908,000 | 2,544 |
| ASTHMA | 125,000,000 | 30,000 |
| HYPERTENSION | 52,900 | 22,325 |

I have tried adding/removing the Distinct from each select statement and the only one that made a difference was removing distinct from this line, in which case I ended up with far too many member counts (even taking into account the duplicate DX counts).

```
,Count(DISTINCT(MEMBER_AMISYS_NBR)) AS MEMBER_COUNT 

The State_Overall_Mbrs table with DX_Flag looks like this and I needed all the diagnosis to be in one column (with duplicate rows for members depending on how many diagnoses they have):

Member ID      Asthma   COPD    Hypertension    Diabetes    CHF
55555555          0       1          1             1         0
66666666          1       0          0             1         0
77777777          0       0          1             0         0
```

Comment: Can you show representative sample data and/or table structures? Does the same source row ever have multiple DX flags set?

Comment: I added a sample of the State_Overall_Mbrs to my question.  Let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize the members table, then join and aggregate; something like this:

```
SELECT 
    DX_FLAG
    ,Sum(AMT_PAID) AS PHARM_PAID_AMT
    ,Count(DISTINCT(MEMBER_AMISYS_NBR)) AS MEMBER_COUNT 
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM State_Overall_Members
    UNPIVOT (has_dx  /* New column to hold the 0 or 1 value */ 
    FOR DX_FLAG IN (Asthma,COPD,Hypertension,Diabetes,CHF)
   /* Original column names become the values in new column DX_FLAG */
    ) nmlz
  WHERE has_dx = 1 /* Only unpivot rows with a 1 in original column */
  ) st
JOIN FT_PHARMACY_CLAIM ph ON st.MEMBER_CURR_CK = ph.PRESCRIBER_MEMBER_CURR_CK AND ph.DELETED_IND = 'N'                        
JOIN DIM_DATE FILL ON ph.FILL_DATE_DIM_CK = FILL.DATE_DIM_CK
 WHERE FILL.DATE_DATE BETWEEN '2021-10-01' AND '2022-09-30'  
          AND ph.PLAN_DIM_CK =10  
      AND  ph.REVERSAL_IND = 'N' 
      AND ph.AMT_PAID > 0
GROUP BY DX_FLAG;
```

Another option to normalize the members table would be to have a subquery for each DX and UNION those, along these lines:

```
... FROM
(SELECT MEMBER_CURR_CK, MEMBER_AMISYS_NBR, AMT_PAID, 'Asthma' (VARCHAR(16)) AS DX_FLAG
   FROM State_Overall_Members
   WHERE Asthma = 1
UNION ALL
 SELECT MEMBER_CURR_CK, MEMBER_AMISYS_NBR, AMT_PAID, 'COPD' (VARCHAR(16)) AS DX_FLAG
   FROM State_Overall_Members
   WHERE COPD = 1
UNION ALL
...
) st
JOIN ...
```

Comment: The first one I tried and got an error (9134) Failure in TD_Unpivot contract function.  I'm googling to see what that means.

Comment: It's a fairly generic error that says something is wrong with the arguments to UNPIVOT. In the `has_dx FOR DX_FLAG IN (...)` clause both "has_dx" and "DX_FLAG" represent new column names that don't exist in the input table, and the names in the parenthesized list must be column names that do exist in the input table and all have the same data type. (The data type in the WHERE clause also needs to match that data type.) Are you using the original table with 0/1 as input or one with character values as in your CASE expressions above?

Comment: Ok I see what I did wrong.  I had a couple columns named wrong! It worked!!! Thanks :)